# How I can get card.io app token?

Tags: ios, objective-c, card.io

How I can get card.io app token? I visited card.io web site but did not find any option to create app token or something similar.

Comment: Why do you need a token? Maybe you don't need a token to use the library?

Comment: Yes you are right. It is not required now in new SDK. Thanks for reply.